# Does enabling Java assertions increase memory consumption significantly?

Tags: java, assertions, jvm-arguments

I've been working on a Java program that reads large CSV files, processes the contents, and submits it to a Solr server depending on certain criteria. The code has been working fine for some time with an initial data set. But as it has not been tested extensively, so I have enabled assertions with the `-ea` flag when running it on another data set of about quadruple size recently (~2.2MB vs ~640KB).

I run into an `OutOfMemoryException` with the new dataset even after doubling max heap size to 8G (`-Xmx8g`). My current code is not particularly memory-efficient, so I am probably able to fix the issue in the code.

However, when reading upon Java assertions, I notice that memory consumption is apparently never discussed in this context. My question is thus: does enabling assertions in the JVM increase memory consumption by a measurable amount? Should this be taken into account when testing/debugging code and when optimizing for memory-efficiency?

Comment: For a fair comparison. Would you try enabling assertions over the 640KB dataset to see if its assertions causing the outOfMemory or its because of data?

Comment: That is a very fair remark. The full process takes a few hours to process though; I'll try that when I have some spare time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, an assertion such as:

```
assert condition : "error message";
```

Gets compiled into a simple check-and-throw statement:

```
if(!$assertionsDisabled && !condition)
    throw new AssertionError("error message");
```

Where `$assertionsDisabled` is a constant field generated by the compiler for each class where assertions are present:

```
static final boolean $assertionsDisabled = !ThisClass.class.desiredAssertionStatus();
```

So I would say that the overhead is quite small, especially memory-wise. I would take a profiler and measure the memory consumption of the given application. You'll probably find out that there are memory issues elsewhere.

Comment: I think that boils it down to the actual point, thanks. To my understanding, however, enabling or disabling assertions should not change memory consumption at all thus, because the assertion code sits in the Jar either way. The only new object that is possibly created when enabling assertions is the AssertionError, but this only happens when the assertion fails and the JVM terminates anyway. The $assertionsDisabled boolean is there either way too (apart from the fact that a boolean primitive only takes very little memory). I assume the memory consumption depends on what happens in `condition`.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure of exact numbers, but i think it'll surely increase the memory consumption a little as it has to execute the assertions.

The memory consumption can increase a lot, but that depends on what you are trying to execute within the assertion body. It might be a huge method call doing intensive work. i.e. the actual work you are doing to assert something. e.g

```
assert(numberOfGrapesInFriutColumn()==5:"Number of grapes is not 5")
```

The method `numberOfGrapesInFriutColumn()` can be iterating over huge collection and doing a instance check or attribute comparison to find if the item is a grape of not.

Comment: In this case, the assertions only operate on independently declared variables (objects and primitives), e.g.
{
[...]
int value = entry.getValue();
assert (value > 0);
[...]
}